# Write Boolean if controller's stick is moving but return always false even if controller's stick and avatar is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

It always returns false and I can see my controller is moving with my avatar (even if I press `Button.One` with the joystick, but returns always false).

I've tried

```
Debug.Log(OVRInput.IsControllerConnected(OVRInput.Controller.RTrackedRemote));
```

because `Debug.Log(OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One));` can't work.

```
Debug.Log(OVRInput.IsControllerConnected(OVRInput.Controller.RTrackedRemote));
Debug.Log(OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One));
```

> false
>   false

and i tried attached OVRManager at Player instead of OVRCameraRig

Comment: In which method do you call `Debug.Log`

Comment: i called in Update()